# How to properly unmount all screens on logout using react-native?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm building an app using react-native and stack navigators, and tab navigators. Screens never unmounts when navigating. I want to unmount the screens when a user press a 'logout' button, so when a new user logs in all screens need to be mounted again without old state preservation.

How can I do this?
Using `this.props.navigation.popToTop()` inside a screen does not work.

My current navigators structure:

```
App DrawerNavigator -> OnBoard Drawer Navigator --> (SignIn screen, SignUp screen)
                    -> Logged Drawer Navigaror --> Home Tab Navigator
                                               --> Settings Stack Navigator -->(Settings screen)
```

I'm calling the logout function inside the Settings screen.

Answer (score 4):

Could you try this??

```js
import { StackActions } from 'react-navigation'; // before
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native'; // current

this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop());
```

Comment: I dont get any error, the function is executed (I have a log before and after) but there is not change on screen, I dont go to the top

Comment: I updated the question adding more info about the general structure of navigators

Comment: @FedericoCaccia  The stack must be at the top.

Comment: why the stack must be at the top?

Comment: @FedericoCaccia You solved it using a switch navigator. It solves your temporary problem, but it doesn't stack up. Only when a stack is a parent's navigator can a stack of screens be stacked.

Comment: Later versions of react the import is actually `import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';`

Answer (score 2):

This will reset whole router and put you on one single screen,

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({ // import StackActions & NavigationActions from react-navigation
  index: 0,
  key: null, // this is important
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "ScreenName" })] // where you want to go after reset
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

if `StackActions` or `NavigationActions` are undefined then you might be using it under other navigations like drawer or tab.
Move this reset code into `stack` or `switch` router screen.

Comment: I put that code on the log out function in the screen settings inside a drawernavigator. The drawernavigator contains two screens: settings and home.
I am trying to redirect user to signIn screen, which is out of the navigator (belongs to a parent navigator of drawernavigator).
I get the following error:
rout is not defined for key SignIn. Must be one of: 'Settings.'

Comment: I updated the question adding more info about the general structure of navigators

Comment: That why i told you that it wont work under tab or drawer navigation. use it inside stack screen and call it using props or event listners

Comment: I used it in a screen inside a stack navigator. You can see the organization of navigators in the question description. Or do you meen that it will not work if the stack navigator is inside another drawer/tabs navigators?

Comment: exactly you need to put it in main stack navigator, nesting a stack inside a  drawer also wont work cause it will reset upto only its stack navigator and will not go up further.

Comment: what do you think about the answer i posted at the bottom, using swithnavigator as a root navigator?

Comment: yes it can work perfectly as switch navigator will render only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the answer. Might be helpful to those who are stuck in the same problem.
The main Navigator must be configured as a SwithNavigator. From [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html):

> The purpose of SwitchNavigator is to only ever show one screen at a time. By default, it does not handle back actions and it resets routes to their default state when you switch away. This is the exact behavior that we want from the authentication flow: when users sign in, we want to throw away the state of the authentication flow and unmount all of the screens, and when we press the hardware back button we expect to not be able to go back to the authentication flow. We switch between routes in the SwitchNavigator by using the navigate action

so, our app needs to be created as following:

```
const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        OnBoard: OnBoardTabsNavigator,
        Logged: LoggedDrawerNavigator,
    }
);
```

then, in the logout screen, configure the following logout function:

```
_LogOut(){
    console.log("Logging out");
    AsyncStorage.clear() // <-- Don't forget to clear any variables stored on Async Storage
    .then(() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('SignIn')
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```